# scrollToRowAtIndexPath from a different thread

Tags: iphone

I am trying to use scrollToRowAtIndexPath on a tableView.
I'm using the method below.

Everything works fine when I'm calling this method by clicking a UIBarButtonItem, means - the tableView scrolls just fine. But, when I'm calling this method from a different thread it doesn't scroll.

ideas?

```
-(void)handleDiffView
{
    NSIndexPath * ndxPath;

    if ( !isLooking ) {
        ndxPath= [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0];
    }
    else {
        ndxPath= [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    }


    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:ndxPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop  animated:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could probably do it by calling `-[NSObject performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:]`, like this:

```
// This will only be called from handleDiffView
- (void)handleDiffViewInMainThread:(NSIndexPath*)ndxPath
{
    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:ndxPath
                          atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop
                                  animated:YES];
}

- (void)handleDiffView {
    NSIndexPath * ndxPath;

    if ( !isLooking ) {
        ndxPath= [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0];
    }
    else {
        ndxPath= [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    }

    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(handleDiffViewInMainThread:)
        withObject:ndxPath waitUntilDone:NO];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From [Graphics and Drawing in iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GraphicsDrawingOverview/GraphicsDrawingOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH14-SW2):

> Important: The UIKit classes are generally not thread safe. All drawing-related operations should be performed on your application’s main thread.

You could use [–performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to invoke a method on the main thread.